# How to change the text color for different mouse motion events?

Tags: java

I have a school assignment to make a program which creates a small window, and when you move the mouse around without clicking it displays the coordinates above in BLACK text, and when you hold and drag the mouse it displays the coordinates above in RED text. I have the program working so it displays the coordinates above the mouse for both events but I'm not sure how to change the color to red when the mouse is being held down. Here is what I have so far:

```
class MyFrame extends Frame{
   int x;
   int y;
   
   public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawString(
             "" + x + ", " + y, x, y);
   }
}

class MyMouseListener extends MouseMotionAdapter{
  MyFrame ref;

  MyMouseListener(MyFrame mFrame){
    ref = mFrame;
  }

  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    ref.x = e.getX();
    ref.y = e.getY();

    ref.repaint();
  }
  
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
    ref.x = e.getX();
    ref.y = e.getY();
   
    ref.repaint();
  }
}
```

Does this need to somehow be done in the mouseDragged() method or in the MyFrame class? Is there any way to make an if statement for which method is being called so I could set a color for if(mouseDragged()) or something like that?

Comment: Assuming you have a public property `color` on ref, just set `ref.color = Color.RED` in mouse dragged method and a similar assignment to black in mouse moved. You can then update your display text to use the color in that variable to render. Exactly the same principle as you were using for coordinates. Or you can leverage mouse up/down the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your paint method call `g.setColor(color)`.
Set the color in mouse events to black and red accordingly.